# Whisper project with CUDO-GPU

Tags: python, gpu, openai-whisper

why I am keep getting this error?

**Process finished with exit code -1073740791 (0xC0000409)**

My code

```
from faster_whisper import WhisperModel
model_size = "large-v2"
model = WhisperModel(model_size, device="cuda", compute_type="float16")
segments, info = model.transcribe("harvard.wav")
for segment in segments:
print(segment.text)
```

Also:

(whisper) PS C:\Users\Desktop\whisper> python -c "import torch; print('CUDA enabled:', torch.cuda.is_available());"

CUDA enabled: True

and same code, but with cpu is working

```
model = WhisperModel(model_size, device="cpu", compute_type="int8")
```